# Get local IP address in VB6 without Winsock control

Tags: vb6, ip, localhost

How can I obtain the local IP addres in VB6 without using Winsock control

The reason I dont want to use or need Winsock is because my application should work offline.

I'm a bit new to VB6 and my search on this subject failed. I suppose that I need some WinAPI's and any pointer or code example would be appreciable.

Comment: Actually, I was not test anything else than winsock. Maybe it's too late to reform my question now, as I ask for method without winsock, and now I have below 2 valid answers. But the bad news for me is that both methods **required** internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was taken from here: [VB Function to Find the IP Address](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/8.htm)

```
Private Declare Function GetIpAddrTable_API Lib "IpHlpApi" Alias "GetIpAddrTable" (pIPAddrTable As Any, pdwSize As Long, ByVal bOrder As Long) As Long

' Returns an array with the local IP addresses (as strings).
' Author: Christian d'Heureuse, www.source-code.biz
Public Function GetIpAddrTable()
   Dim Buf(0 To 511) As Byte
   Dim BufSize As Long: BufSize = UBound(Buf) + 1
   Dim rc As Long
   rc = GetIpAddrTable_API(Buf(0), BufSize, 1)
   If rc <> 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "GetIpAddrTable failed with return value " & rc
   Dim NrOfEntries As Integer: NrOfEntries = Buf(1) * 256 + Buf(0)
   If NrOfEntries = 0 Then GetIpAddrTable = Array(): Exit Function
   ReDim IpAddrs(0 To NrOfEntries - 1) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 0 To NrOfEntries - 1
      Dim j As Integer, s As String: s = ""
      For j = 0 To 3: s = s & IIf(j > 0, ".", "") & Buf(4 + i * 24 + j): Next
      IpAddrs(i) = s
      Next
   GetIpAddrTable = IpAddrs
   End Function



' Test program for GetIpAddrTable.
Public Sub Test()
   Dim IpAddrs
   IpAddrs = GetIpAddrTable
   Debug.Print "Nr of IP addresses: " & UBound(IpAddrs) - LBound(IpAddrs) + 1
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = LBound(IpAddrs) To UBound(IpAddrs)
      Debug.Print IpAddrs(i)
      Next
   End Sub
```

I tested it on my machine, it resulted in 2 IpAddrs. I would usually consider the 2nd one to be my actual one.

Comment: Many thanks! Looks like the next time I should search more harder before asking.On my XP the 2nd address is my actual IP. I'll test that function on Win7/8 as well but this is my homework.

Answer (score 4):

This is a function I like to use, no need for an API:

```
Public Function getIP()

Dim WMI     As Object
Dim qryWMI  As Object
Dim Item    As Variant

    Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

    Set qryWMI = WMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " & _
                               "WHERE IPEnabled = True")

    For Each Item In qryWMI
      getIP = Item.IPAddress(0)
    Next

    Set WMI = Nothing
    Set qryWMI = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Looks like cannot accept more than 1 answer, but many thanks for your solution! I using WMI in VBScript but somehow forget about it, shame for me :)

Comment: @PanayotKarabakalov That's ok, happy to help